# View files from my application

Tags: android, android-intent, blackberry-10

Is there any way to open/view/display a file on BlackBerry 10, using the Android SDK, since according to [BlackBerry documentation for Android apps](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_intents.html)   the Intent.ACTION_VIEW command is not supported?